# CSS Grid Last row 2 column

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

I want to create a form that has 2 buttons at the last row and to be aligned to the right. I am using CSS grid. What i am doing wrong here in the screenshot?

[image]
**css
**

```
.wrapper {
    width:75%;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    background: white;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 35% 65%;

    .grid-item {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #4D4D4D;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        border: 1px solid #828995;
        height: 20px;
    }
    label {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #4D4D4D;
        padding: 14px 0 0 0;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: "Corpid";
    } 

}
```

```
<form>
        <div className="wrapper">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email*</label>
          <input id="email" type="text" className="grid-item"/>
          <label htmlFor="name">Name*</label>
          <input id="name" type="text" className="grid-item"/>
          <BaseButton >{"Back"}</BaseButton>
          <BaseButton>{"Send"}</BaseButton>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
    width:75%;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    background: white;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 35% 65%;
}
    .grid-item {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #4D4D4D;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        border: 1px solid #828995;
        height: 20px;
    }
    label {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #4D4D4D;
        padding: 14px 0 0 0;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: "Corpid";
    } 
    .buttons-wrapper {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: end;
color: red;
width: 100%;
grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<form>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email*</label>
          <input id="email" type="text" class="grid-item"/>
          <label htmlFor="name">Name*</label>
          <input id="name" type="text" class="grid-item"/>
          <div class="buttons-wrapper">
           <div >{"Back"}</div>
           <div>{"Send"}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

I'm adding a new div element so I can wrap the two elements and then set their display to flex and direction to row so we can keep them in the same row and then we justify the content of `buttons-wrapper` to the right...
That should handle your case.

```
<form>
        <div className="wrapper">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email*</label>
          <input id="email" type="text" className="grid-item"/>
          <label htmlFor="name">Name*</label>
          <input id="name" type="text" className="grid-item"/>
          <div className="buttons-wrapper">
           <BaseButton >{"Back"}</BaseButton>
           <BaseButton>{"Send"}</BaseButton>
          </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

```
.buttons-wrapper {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: end;
width: 100%;
grid-column: span 2;
}
```

Comment: And how can i make the last row only one column?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly I mean how do you want to see the two buttons.

Comment: The wrapper are having 2 columns in each row, so i want the last row to be on column and the 2buttons inside it aligned to right

Comment: that's exactly what `buttons-wrapper` css does... did you copy and test the code I just posted?

Comment: @reactDev - I edited the answer to fit your case.

Comment: Super, but the two buttons are now attached to each other :(

Comment: You can add gap to space them...

Comment: in the `.buttons-wrapper` you can add `gap` attribute and set it to the amount of `px` that you want them to be spaced if you want to learn more about flex layout and gap https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-gap-space-with-flexbox